# How to create a dictionary and populate the key and values with the results of a SQL query in Python?

Tags: python, sql, dictionary-comprehension

I am looking to make a calendar that shows on what day specific updates were made. I ran a SQL query and get a list of tuples which show the month number and the day

```
[(5,4),(5,7),(5,8),.......,(10,30),(11,1)]
```

I want to create a dictionary where the key is the first number, ie the month, and the values are the days, but I can't seem to figure it out.

My very basic code is as follows:

```
m={5: [], 6:[], 7:[], 8:[], 10:[], 11:[]}
for i in y:
    day=m.get([i[0])
    day.append(i[1])
```

This fills up each list with all the values from the query.

I can't seem to figure out how to map the key to each key in the tuple and add the value to the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet does the job, but you have to pre-fill your dictionary with entries that map a month to an empty list. That's  because you miss something like: "if this month is not in the dictionary, then create a new entry that maps it to an empty list".
In Python, this is fairly easy:

```
if k not in d:
    d[k] = []
```

Hence you can write:

```
>>> months_days = [(5,4),(5,7),(5,8),(10,30),(11,1)]
>>> d = {}
>>> for month, day in months_days: # destructuring assignment to unpack the tuple
...     if month not in d:
...             d[month] = []
...     d[month].append(day)
... 
>>> d
{5: [4, 7, 8], 10: [30], 11: [1]}
```

You have even a [`setdefault` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to make it more concise:

> If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with a value of default and return default. default defaults to None.

Example:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for month, day in months_days:
...     d.setdefault(month, []).append(day)
... 
>>> d
{5: [4, 7, 8], 10: [30], 11: [1]}
```

Or you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> import collections
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for month, day in months_days:
...     d[month].append(day)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {5: [4, 7, 8], 10: [30], 11: [1]})
```

The `defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`, therefore you can use a `defaultdict` as a `dict`.